# Add optional docstring to def* macros

Tags: macros, clojure

I want to add optional docstrings to my `def*` macros. For example:

```
(defmacro defhtml
  "Macro to avoid backtick unquote[splicing] in html vectors.
   TODO: Add optional docstring."
  [name args & body]
  `(defn ~name ~args (html ~@body)))

;; Working defhtml
(defhtml include-css [href]
  [:link {:href href :rel "stylesheet"}])
```

I would like:

```
(defhtml include-css
  "My optional docstring here."
  [:link {:href href :rel "stylesheet"}])
```

I figure there should be some common idiom for this.

Comment: I think you want to add optional docstrings to *the invocations of* your def* macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to decision off of whether or not the second argument to your macro is a doc-string (you can test if it's a string).  Clojure macros are Clojure, so you can perform any logic or manipulations on the forms passed to the macro that you want to.  This should be close to if not exactly what you're after:

```
(defmacro defhtml [name & args]
  (cond
    ;; doc-string?
    (string? (first args))
    (let [[doc-string args-list & body] args]
      `(defn ~name ~doc-string ~args-list (html ~@body)))

    :no-doc-string
    (let [[args-list & body] args]
      `(defn ~name ~(format "HTML Generator %s" name) ~args-list (html ~@body)))))
```

That should produce the macro expansions you're after:

```
(defhtml include-css [href]
  [:link {:href href :rel "stylesheet"}])
```

produces:

```
(defn include-css
    "HTML Generator include-css"
  [href]
  (html [:link {:href href, :rel "stylesheet"}]))
```

while:

```
(defhtml include-css
  "Standard css includes fory my site"
  [href]
  [:link {:href href :rel "stylesheet"}])
```

produces:

```
(defn include-css
    "Standard css includes fory my site"
  [href]
  (html [:link {:href href, :rel "stylesheet"}]))
```

Answer (score 2):

`defn` and `defmacro` already support *optional* docstrings, so if your `def*` macro expands to a call to one of these, you may not need to include any `string?` checks in your own code. This is the case with `defhtml`, which can be implemented thus:

```
;; also adding an optional attribute map parameter, because why not?
(defmacro defhtml [name doc? attr-map? params & body]
  `(defn ~name ~doc? ~attr-map? ~params (html ~@body)))

;; equivalent, perhaps prettier:
(defmacro defhtml [name doc? attr-map? params & body]
  `(defn ~@[name doc? attr-map? params] (html ~@body)))
```

Comment: `def` also accepts an optional docstring argument, but this is not much help in writing macros that take an optional docstring and a *body* (of arbitrarily many expressions) and expand directly to `def`.